# How to run a batch file which is present in the working directory of the java file?

Tags: java, batch-file

The answer which the other use shown and marked as duplicate still doesn't work.

Instead of marking it duplicate and refusing the question it would be better to answer it and make sure that the asker of the question that is me is satisfied with the answer.

I want to run a Batch file whose name is **Test.bat** and which is present in the same directory where this java file would be executed and the directory string is stored in **dir** but I have tried the following code to call it but it is not working.

Please someone help me with this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");   
    dir = dir.replace('\\','/');

    System.out.println("current dir = " + dir);

    ProcessBuilder batch = new ProcessBuilder("Test.bat");
    try {
        batch.start();
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not using the dir value.  should you be passing     `ProcessBuilder batch = new ProcessBuilder(dir+"/Test.bat");`

Comment: You may want to read [Executing a Command](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html), [Reading Output from a Command](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.lang/ReadFromCommand.html), [Sending Input to a Command](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.lang/WriteToCommand.html)

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I don't think the question you marked as duplicate answers this question. The answer here is that he needs to call `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`. I don't see that answer in the linked duplicate that you suggested.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I changed the answer for another one that seems more appropriate.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I have already told I have tried all the answers and the answer which you have suggested doesn't work

Comment: @JerinJoseph I have tried your answer but still It did not work :(